# Print PDF from WebView which has URL. Objective C macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, pdf, cocoa, printing

I want to print a `PDF` file from `WebView` as there is a print button in WebView and when I click it, I'll get the `URL of PDF` and its `content type` as `application/pdf`. I searched so much and exhausted for `how to print a PDF file in Objective C - cocoa`. All I saw is to `print` content from `a view` and it'll print all the WebView

`[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:webView]`

**But I need to print the PDF I got, not the entire WebView**

Please help me...

**NB Swift coders: Please don't put your code here. I don't know swift**

Edit 1: **No iOS codes please. Its about macOS**

Edit 2: From the screenshot, when I click print, I get that PDF in the PDF viewer in the WebView. I need to print it directly. Thats my scenario.

[image: Printing PDF that we get from web]

Comment: Do you want to print a pdf or do you want to download and save a file or do you want to print the downloaded file? Which data do you have and which step is the problem?

Comment: I want to print a pdf

Comment: With which data?

Comment: I have a url which contains a pdf file. I need to print it. Thats where I got stuck.

Comment: @soorejbabu, can you save the pdf locally or in memory? I understand the question is not really related to webview. So, if you can load the pdf 
 from its URL in the WebView to a NSData object or PDFDocument, then you can print it easily using coca printing api.
This is an example of how to print a PDFDocument from file URL.
http://www.danandcheryl.com/2010/05/how-to-print-a-pdf-file-using-cocoa
Let me know!

Comment: Duplicate of [Printing without an NSView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881635/printing-without-an-nsview)

Comment: Duplicate of [cocoa osx print pdf document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750605/cocoa-osx-print-pdf-document)

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA I gone through the link and it worked. But it need to modify as there will be exception appear if we print it or cancel it. So slightly modified the code. Anyway it helped me a lot.

Comment: @soorejbabu that's great!

Answer (score 0):

did you try this? It explains how to render PDF document from a UIWebView on iOS. If it works on iOS, my first guess would we that it should on macos.

Good luck!
Hichem

[Creating PDF file from UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813005/creating-pdf-file-from-uiwebview)

Comment: Oh no... This question is not about iOS/CocoaTouch. Its about macOS/Cocoa. At least look those tags please

Comment: And it's about rendering the entire WebView.

Comment: After a small search I can see that iOS Print Rendering api does not exist on Mac, so the solution is not so obvious :/

You can take a look at this thread. It is related to the same subject and can give you more insight and sample code to generate the PDF on MAC.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947782/how-to-create-a-pdf-in-swift-with-cocoa-mac]